Failed to request allowed query parameters from WebPrivacy
Experiencing the error/warning: “Failed to request allowed query parameters from WebPrivacy” on a brand new CapacitorJS project on iOS using xCode 15+
The error appears in the console as shown below right after initialization of the Capacitor into the WebView. This originally happend on a main project but we haven’t been able to find any errors within the code that regards the Webprivacy query parameters. Also the app works with no bugs. We then went forward by trying to create a new Capacitor project just to see and if the error still appears. And it does. So do anyone have an idea what could cause this?
Here is a link to the repo:
https://github.com/jonasbehlic/WebPrivacyIOS
Xcode Console output:

-> Warning: -[BETextInput attributedMarkedText] is unimplemented ⚡️ Loading app at capacitor://localhost...
-> Failed to request allowed query parameters from WebPrivacy. ⚡️ WebView loaded ⚡️ To Native -> SplashScreen hide 111656092 ⚡️ TO JS
undefined


It seems to be a bug on Apples side.

Possibly. So far, looks like people can safely ignore this error message?

@auspicious99 yes it seems like it Apple told me I could categorize it as “Log noise”.

Thanks, good to know that they said that.

https://example.com/page?param1=value1&param2=value2
Try sending parameters like this
It works for me.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
